# SSH command step not working for one command - in Jmeter

Tags: ssh, jmeter

I have a unique problem using jmeter SSH command.
I use this step to run spark jobs.
the problem is that one of the commands not working, to clarify it connects and not get response and just wait and wait for hours, and nothing displayed on screen.

I know how to work with the tool, and this behavior is special for this script alone.

All other script worked, I duplicate one that worked for example
sudo /run_stg.sh this command worked
sudo /run_off2-stg.sh this command not worked

if I run the job manually via jenkins it worked
if I entered to command line and use plik ssh it worked,

the problem is just Jmeter, that is waiting and waiting and I can not understand for what?
the job is about 3 minutes, and I wait for response in Jmeter for 4 hours and nothing Jmeter just waiting.

in the console log I set to trace level and nothing, absolutely no idea how to start handle this issue in Jmeter.

an anyone please assists how to make Jmeter to write what happened? 
or just to know if he connect or anything

since this behavior all the test can not be performed

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are as usual misconfiguring the SSH Command sampler.

The idea is not to run the script per se, you need to delegate the script execution to the [Unix Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), for example [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) this way you will be able to combine several commands together, see the output, [amend debugging level](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

So I would recommend setting your command to something like `/bin/bash -c -x /your/script.sh`

[image: JMeter SSH Command]

---

Another guess, given you use `sudo` it might be the case that the `sudo` command simply waits for the password (which JMeter never provides), if this is the case try amending your script permissions using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command and allowing your user its execution without root privileges.

And finally, given you're able to run your command using "plik ssh" (whatever it is) you can run it using [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)